# Checking union equality

Tags: c++, equality, unions

```
struct Something {
    union {
        float k;
        int n;
    };

    bool isFloat;

    bool operator==(const Something& mS)
    {
        if(isFloat != mS.isFloat) return false;
        if(isFloat && mS.k == k) return true;
        if(!isFloat && mS.n == n) return true;
    }
};
```

My implementation of `Something::operator==` seems rather expensive and convoluted. Is this the only way to check equality in classes with union types?

Or is there a better way that avoids branches/checking additional variables?

Comment: Try to avoid unions at all. You should probably be using templates instead. Or templates and template specializations.

Comment: @Captain: There's nothing undefined here -- the bool ensures that only one member of the union is accessible at a time.

Comment: The check is already good, by no means expensive. One thing: you should mark the method `const`, as you're not modifying the object.

Comment: I initially thought a bit & might be a little cheaper but the float value means you have to check isFloat. So no, you need to check isFloat. See my answer below for a cleaner version though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool operator==(const Something& mS)
{
    if (isFloat != mS.isFloat)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (isFloat)
    {
        return mS.k == k;
    }
    else
    {
        return mS.n == n;
    }
}
```

Clear and debuggable with the minimum number of checks. You want to have a constructor and/or set methods to ensure isFloat is correct at all times.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove one redundant check, and perhaps enhance readability slightly, by replacing the last two lines with

```
if(isFloat != mS.isFloat) return false; // As you have
return isFloat ? mS.k == k : mS.n == n;
```

(or the equivalent `if` construct, as in Sean Perry's answer) but the compiler will probably do just as good a job of optimising your version.

There's no way to avoid a runtime check that the types match. You might consider a ready-made discriminated union type like Boost.Variant; it won't be any more efficient, but it might be easier and less error-prone to use.

Comment: "There's no way to avoid a runtime check that the types match." That's what I wanted to be sure about. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is incorrect though, I need to check `mS.isFloat` too.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Just replace the last two lines, as I said. Keep the first line to check that the types match first.

Comment: I use the if/else construct because a) it lets the code adapt over time and b) it gives me a place to put breaks in the debugger when I am saying "that can't happen". Otherwise Mike's version is equivalent to mine. I always use braces for the same code always gets updated reason. You can leave them off to keep the original minimal style.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (isFloat && mS.isFloat && k==mS.k) || (!isFloat && !mS.isFloat && n==mS.n);
```

Comment: This is no less expensive or less convoluted than the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can escape checking all the conditions. So the question can be how to write them more simpler and expressively.

I would write them the following way

```
bool operator==( const Something &mS ) const
{
    return  ( ( isFloat == mS.isFloat ) && ( isFloat ? k == mS.k : n == mS.n ) );
}
```